# Get first value of comma separated string

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looking for the quickest/shortest way to get the first value from comma separated string, **in-line**.

The best I can do is

```
$string = 'a,b,c,d';
echo "The first thing is " . end(array_reverse(explode(',', $string))) . ".";
```

but I feel that's excessive and redundant. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
echo reset(explode(',', 'a,b,c,d'))
```

Answer (score 9):

```
list($first) = explode(',', 'a,b,c,d');
var_dump($first);  // a
```

probably works :)

---

In PHP 6.0 you will be able to simply:

```
$first = explode(',', 'a,b,c,d')[0];
```

But this is a syntax error in 5.x and lower

Comment: Isn't `list()` a bit excessive in this case?

Comment: My option seems more logical/simpler, but maybe that's just me ;)

Comment: In your first solution `list()` returns an array. I like your second solution though. Wish it worked in earlier versions.

Comment: What do you mean? `list()` doesn't return anything, it's not a function. It's on the _left_ side of the assignment.

Comment: `literal dereferencing` is announced in PHP 5.5 so doesn't have any syntactical error.

Comment: The $first = explode(',', 'a,b,c,d')[0]; seems the simplest and direct

Answer (score 8):

Steve

It's little bit shorter

```
strtok('a,b,c,d', ",")
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php    
$array = explode(',', 'a,b,c,d');
$first = $array [0];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        $int = substr($string,0,strpos($string,","));
```

Comment: Please provide some detail about what are you doing for further detail!

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users also with similar issues.